# "Otherwise" usage and Sentence Structure

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have a hard time understanding this sentence,

> How could it be otherwise with so strange and masterful an artist?

This sentence confuses me in two points,

1. What's the meaning of **otherwise** here, I tried to substitute **otherwise** with **alternative** and similar words. But it didn't work so well.
2. The sentence structure is somehow reverted here and I had a hard time to revert it back. If I can revert it, I think I can have a better chance understanding the meaning of **otherwise** here.

Comment: Please see **[this link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/otherwise?s=t)**, definition #5.

Comment: If you look in a good English dictionary (not a translation dictionary), you will find meanings like  **In a different state or situation** so you can then try **different** in the sentence. here is a good dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case *otherwise* means different,

> How could it be **different** with so strange and masterful artist?

It was a response sentence though, so it might be easier to understand if you had full context

another example of this would sound like;

> "that cake was very flavorful," "What would you expect **otherwise (differently)** from such a skillful chef?